# Unable to extend type bounds in scala for implementations

Tags: scala, existential-type

I want to define an abstract variable with type bound in trait and implement in the respective extended class. Something similar to this

```scala
  trait Animal {
    def makeSound(): Unit
  }

  class Lion extends Animal {
    override def makeSound(): Unit = println("Roar")
    def scarySound(): Unit = println("Rooooaaarrrrr")
  }

  trait AnimalCostume {
    val animal: _ <: Animal
    def locate(): Unit = {
      animal.makeSound()
    }
  }

  class LionCostume extends AnimalCostume {
    override val animal = new Lion()
    def scareEveryOne(): Unit = animal.scarySound()
  }
```

The code is not compiling with the following exception

```
unbound wildcard type
    val animal: _ <: Animal
```

Can you help in understanding how do I achieve something like this and why it is failing with error that type is not bounded if I have explicitly defined the upper bound here

Comment: The error is because what you wrote means something very different to what you want and I won't go into detail because is a very advanced feature. - Anyways, depending on what is your end goal we can do multiple things but I would start with the simple version like `trait AnimalCostume[A <: Animal] { val animal: A }`

Comment: Understood the approach with type parameter. Any resources or key words I can look for to make myself clear with the issue in first case

Comment: Existential types, but really I haven't used those not even once in more than 5 years using **Scala**.

Comment: Existential types are almost never useful. It's also deprecated in Scala 3. Even if your code compiles, it's just equivalent to `val animal: Animal`. Using a named type class parameter, or a member type is more useful. Otherwise you can just use Any

Comment: @SwiftMango Existential types are not deprecated in Scala 3. `forSome`-types are deprecated, wildcarded types are not. https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html